# Number of ways two matrices can be multiplied?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, matrix-equations

Given the dimensions of two matrices what are the different ways they can be multiplied?
Example $A[2][2]$ and $B[2][2]$ then answer is $2$.
Let the dimensions of first matrix be $n \times m$ and second be $m \times p$.

Comment: What constitutes a "way to be multiplied"?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that by "different ways" you mean different orders, then using the fact that $AB$ is defined iff the number of columns of $A$ is the number of rows of $B$, then the answer is as follows:

If the dimensions of $A$ are $m \times n$ and those of $B$ are $m' \times n'$ then:

- there are two ways ($AB$, $BA$) if $n' = m$ and $n = m'$,
- there is one way ($AB$) if $n = m'$ and $n' \neq m$,
- there is one way ($BA$) if $n' = m$ and $n \neq m'$, amd
- there are no ways if $n' \neq m$ and $n \neq m'$.

Comment: Did you mean *"there are two ways ($AB$, $BA$) if $m = n'$ and $m' = n$"* (removing an $=$ and reordering)?

Comment: Yes, of course---thanks, Henry. I've fixed that and uniformized how the conditions are written too.